# Ansible not reading credentials from ~/.aws/credentials

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ansible, aws-cli

I am running ansible with `dynamic inventory`. When the `aws cli` was setup with aws configure command than the ansible commands with dynamic invetory was running properly. But I want to have multiple profiles to be used by dynamic inventory so I have added profile in `~/.aws/credentials`

```
[personal]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX

[default]
aws_access_key_id = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
aws_secret_access_key = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

ansible not picking up these credentials and on running `./ec2.py --list` it is giving the error:

```
Looks like AWS is down again:
EC2ResponseError: 401 Unauthorized
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>AuthFailure</Code><Message>Authorization header or parameters are not formatted correctly.</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>349d5311-54db-4e79-9bbc-2d60b9f15da5</RequestID></Response>
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue too, and eventually solved it; the problem was that the clock on my machine had drifted by a couple of minutes.  Setting the time correctly fixed the issue.

Along the way I learned that aws cli uses boto3, whereas ec2.py uses boto.  It seems that boto3 works slightly differently for authentication, because like @drishti the CLI was working for me even when ec2.py was not.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding --profile PROFILE switch to ec2.py as below.

```
./ec2.py --list --profile personal
```

Comment: it is giving error - `usage: hosts [-h] [--list] [--host HOST] [--refresh-cache]
hosts: error: unrecognized arguments: --profile personal`

Comment: Can you make sure you have the latest ec2.py file. The one I have has --profile option


  `./ec2.py --help
usage: ec2.py [-h] [--list] [--host HOST] [--refresh-cache]
              [--profile BOTO_PROFILE]`

Comment: Pasting the [ec2.py link](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/contrib/inventory/ec2.py)

Comment: yes you are right. Now i have the latest ec2.py but still it gives the error - `ERROR: "Authentication error retrieving ec2 inventory.
 - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY environment vars found but may not be correct
 - Boto configs found at '~/.boto, ~/.aws/credentials', but the credentials contained may not be correct", while: getting EC2 instances`

Answer (score 0):

After @uptime365's answer, this is most likely not an Ansible/ec2.py problem. Here's my troubleshooting steps:

#### Can you use the `awscli` with those credentials?

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --page-size 5
aws ec2 describe-instances --page-size 5 --profile personal
```

### Can you use `awscli` with the credentials manually included?

Note there's no need to use `profile` since you are specifying the keys.

```
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="AKIA.." AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=".."  aws ec2 describe-instances --page-size 5
```

If it complains about the region, add `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-east-1"` or the region of your choice.

### Neither of these work

You have a problem with your access key or secret. How many characters are in each? The key should be 20 characters, all uppercase letters and numbers. The secret is 40 characters, upper/lower/numbers/punctuation.

Comment: its working with `aws ec2 describe-instances --page-size 5 --profile personal` but when I run `./ec2.py --list --profile personal`, 
it gives error - 
`ERROR: "Authentication error retrieving ec2 inventory.
 - AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY environment vars found but may not be correct
 - Boto configs found at '~/.boto, ~/.aws/credentials', but the credentials contained may not be correct", while: getting EC2 instances`

Comment: Add the profile before ec2.py like this: `AWS_PROFILE=personal ./ec2.py`

Comment: paste the **entire** ec2.py into a [gist](https://gist.github.com/). There's something you haven't shared that is causing this to fail. Maybe also a copy of your screen, showing the files, how you are running them, username, host, etc.

Comment: Here is the gist - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bdd30431d32323282c0496f087b45776

Comment: What version of boto? (`pip freeze | grep boto`)

Comment: this is the output - `boto==2.42.0
botocore==1.4.49`

Comment: Any suggestion about this?

Comment: No, the information given does not explain the problem. I can't help with the unknowns.

Comment: the aws-cli is working fine with the credentials. its just that ansible dynamic inventory is not picking up the credentials.